# Swift error while operations with NSNumbers

Tags: ios, swift, nsnumber

I'm using this code in a Swift project

```
        var coreDataArray:NSArray = fetchFromCoreData() // Return an array of record
        var mediumValue:NSNumber
        var tmp:NSNumber

        for(var i = 0; i < coreDataArray.count; ++i)
        {
            tmp = coreDataArray[i].score // The .score value is set as Float in .xcdatamodel
            mediumValue = mediumValue + tmp
        }
```

i get this error on the line `mediumValue = mediumValue + tmp`

```
Could not find an overload for '+' that accepts the supplied arguments
```

Any advice??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't add `NSNumber`'s together—they are simply objects that encapsulate number values.

Instead of making `mediumValue` an `NSNumber`, try using a `Float` instead.

Comment: yeah i managed to solve forcing all of them to be `Floats`right now!

Comment: @ObiWanKeNerd you got that figured out just before I edited it into the post :)